# .csv File changes to .txt when emailing in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a program that stores tweets in a csv file, then emails them via Gmail. Everything seems to be working, until I get to the part where I send the email. Instead of the file coming over as .csv, it is sent via .txt. I have tried to figure it out using the email.mime documentation on the official python website, but it's extremely hard to understand without any sort of examples.

Here is a snippet of the code I currently have:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = user
msg['To'] = receiver
msg['Subject'] = 'Here are some tweets'

body = 'Enjoy these tweets'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
filename = 'tweets.csv'
attachment = open('tweets.csv', 'rb')

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Dispostition', 'attchment; filename %s' %       (filename))

msg.attach(part)
text = msg.as_string()
```

Comment: You have typos in your headers, which almost certainly won't help. Misspelling `Disposition` and `attachment` ensures whatever is trying to interpret your message will interpret it incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks. I went in and corrected that, and tried the code again, but it still sent the attachment as .txt instead of .csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same code I used to send `csv` file using `SMTPlib` hope this will help you. The `add_header` part in your code is not in the format as stated [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.add_header) in `python` docs

```
msg=MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = user
msg['To'] = receiver
msg['Subject'] = 'Here are some tweets'
filename="tweets.csv"
ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
if ctype is None or encoding is not None:
    ctype       = "application/octet-stream"

maintype, subtype = ctype.split("/", 1)

body = 'Enjoy these tweets'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))
attachment                = open(filename, "rb")
part        = MIMEBase(maintype, subtype)
part.set_payload(attachment.read())
attachment.close()
part.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename=filename)
msg.attach(part)

server            =  smtplib.SMTP()
server.connect(address,port)
server.ehlo()

server.sendmail(from, to, msg.as_string())
server.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your method helped; I also realized that I could do the following:

    part = MIMEText('attachment.read(), _subtype='csv'

and that allowed it to be sent as csv. Thanks again!